# Random <a> tag will not go away

Tags: php, html, css

I have this simple website built with a 3x4 CSS grid. But for some reason when I check the page in chrome 'Inspect' there's this weird empty `<a> </a>` tag that is clearly not in my code. **It's causing an extra row to appear on the website**, resulting in a 4x4 grid instead.

It's right in between the main content and the footer like this in the chrome Inspect:

[image]

But my code looks like this:

[image: My source code]

If i remove the `<a></a>`tag in chrome Inspect the website returns to normal.

Here is an image of the displayed grids in chrome inspect.

[image]

**Please help me figure out why it is apearing and how to get rid of it, thank you!**

Comment: Your a tag within your button is not closed correctly <a/> should be </a

Comment: `<a>` should be closed as `</a>` not `<a/>`. Chrome is trying to auto fix this for you and what you see is what chrome thinks you actually want. Its a typo error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stray `<a/>` is right there, after the word "Statistics". That's causing you problems. It should probably be a `</a>` tag, to close the opening anchor-tag.

The reason why this is blowing up on you is because Chrome sees `<a/>`, thinks "Oh, a self-closing element!", and includes both tags, the opening and closing. But you already opened a `<a>`, so what you really want is `</a>`, not `<a/>`. Spot the difference?